# mod_rewrite is behaving strangely - some RewriteRules work and others don't

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a list of about 40 RewriteRules, all pointing to the same page, but with a different query string.

Most (37) of the rewrites work properly.  Here are examples:

```
RewriteRule ^absa/?$ /register.php?company=absa [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^crc/?$  /register.php?company=crc [NC,L]
```

But 3 of them don't work at all and throw a server error.  They aren't any different, as far as I can tell.

```
RewriteRule ^bv/?$  /register.php?company=bv [NC,L]
```

I've tried restarting Apache, I've visited `register.php?company=bv` and it works just fine, and I'm all out of ideas.

Anyone know what might be going on?

Thanks.

Comment: Which 3 don't work? Supply the 3 that don't work, and others which do

Comment: The three that don't work are "ge", "bv", and "qafco".  There are numerous others that work.

Comment: I just tried visiting the same page (in this case, the "ge" page) twice.  The first time it threw a server error, and the second time it worked.  Now it works every time.  I've also confirmed this with the other two.  So, I suppose the problem is fixed, but I'd still like to know what was causing it.

Comment: You need to say exactly what the error messages are.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer (since you haven't provided all the details like error.log) but you can reduce your total # of rules dramatically like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(crc|absa|bv|ge|qafco)/?$  /register.php?company=$1 [NC,L]
```